# How to form a "GET :urn/manifest/:derivativeurn" request?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I don't get how to download a created derivative from Forge.

Here is what I get from the "GET :urn/manifest" request:

```
{
"type": "manifest",
"hasThumbnail": "false",
"status": "success",
"progress": "complete",
"region": "US",
"urn": "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6ZGVyaXZhdGV0bXAvU3QlQzMlQTRuZGVyX1lfT2JlbiUyMHYxLmYzZA",
"version": "1.0",
"derivatives": [
    {
        "name": "Ständer_Y_Oben v1.f3d",
        "hasThumbnail": "false",
        "status": "success",
        "progress": "complete",
        "outputType": "obj",
        "children": [
            {
                "guid": "4064073b-a56c-4007-8b87-3cf87c821361",
                "type": "resource",
                "role": "obj",
                "status": "success",
                "progress": "complete",
                "mime": "application/octet-stream",
                "urn": "urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6ZGVyaXZhdGV0bXAvU3QlQzMlQTRuZGVyX1lfT2JlbiUyMHYxLmYzZA/output/files/6f7db9b2-925f-44b3-92e8-a5aeeb3954d2/Ständer_Y_Oben v1.obj"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

So how to form a valid "GET :urn/manifest/:derivativeurn" request with that? The docs say "urn should be The Base64 (URL Safe) encoded design URN" and "derivativeurn should be The URL-encoded URN of the derivatives.".

For me this results in:
https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6ZGVyaXZhdGV0bXAvU3QlQzMlQTRuZGVyX1lfT2JlbiUyMHYxLmYzZA/manifest/urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6ZGVyaXZhdGV0bXAvU3QlQzMlQTRuZGVyX1lfT2JlbiUyMHYxLmYzZA/output/files/6f7db9b2-925f-44b3-92e8-a5aeeb3954d2/St%C3%A4nder_Y_Oben%20v1.obj

But the result always is the message "The requested derivative is not belongs to the design data.".

So what is wrong? The docs or me?

Regards,
Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to documentation of [GET :urn/manifest/:derivativeurn](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-manifest-derivativeurn-GET/), the `derivativeurn` should be escaped into a URL safe form since there are some reserved and unsafe keywords ( i.e. `:`, `.`, `?` and `=` ) in this parameter. They will invalid your request to the Forge service. ([Ref](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt))

Your file urn is:
`urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6ZGVyaXZhdGV0bXAvU3QlQzMlQTRuZGVyX1lfT2JlbiUyMHYxLmYzZA/output/files/6f7db9b2-925f-44b3-92e8-a5aeeb3954d2/Ständer_Y_Oben v1.obj`

To download this file, you have to transform it into this form: `urn%3Aadsk.viewing%3Afs.file%3AdXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6ZGVyaXZhdGV0bXAvU3QlQzMlQTRuZGVyX1lfT2JlbiUyMHYxLmYzZA%2Foutput%2Ffiles%2F6f7db9b2-925f-44b3-92e8-a5aeeb3954d2%2FSt%C3%A4nder_Y_Oben%20v1.obj`

In JavaScript, the `encodeURIComponent()`([Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-TW/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)) function can help you do this transformation. Here is a sample for you:

`encodeURIComponent('urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6ZGVyaXZhdGV0bXAvU3QlQzMlQTRuZGVyX1lfT2JlbiUyMHYxLmYzZA/output/files/6f7db9b2-925f-44b3-92e8-a5aeeb3954d2/Ständer_Y_Oben v1.obj')`

If you are coding in C#, `Uri.EscapeDataString()` ([Ref](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapedatastring(v=vs.110).aspx)) can help you to archive the same goal.

Comment: Thx Eason! I used encodeURI() instead of encodeURIComponent(), so this was the problem.

Comment: Hi @MHilgers , I still get the message you mentioned with encodeURI(). encodeURIComponent() returns "The requested derivative urn is invalid."

Comment: same here, have tried several objects and they all return "The requested derivative is not belongs to the design data."

Comment: May need more details to understand the problems, could you consider booking Forge experts with your convenient time? https://calendly.com/autodeskforge

Comment: Hi, I'm having the same issue when using `encodeURIComponent()` with the node.js API. Were you able to find a solution?